# Don't animate if already animating

Tags: jquery

Going mad. I had this working and then stupidly overwrote my code without a backup, and now can't remember how I did it!

I have a drop down social yeti: http://projects.jonhudsonweb.com/work

However if you repeatedly run mouse over it it repeats the animation again and again. Here is my failed effort to stop this:

```
$('#social-yeti').not(':animated').hoverIntent(function(){
    $(this).delay(300).animate({top:"+=203"}, 1000)
    }, function(){
    $(this).delay(300).animate({top:"-=203"}, 1000)
    } 
);
```

I'm sure this is how I did it before though! Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I like to make hover like this ( ..and multiple events in one element in general ): http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/EUqKN/ Mainly because I can define 1 variable for `$(this)` instead of having to make multiple variables inside each event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing the **.stop()** method before animating:

```
$('#social-yeti').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ top:"0" }, 1000);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ top:"-203" }, 1000);
});
```

This will basically clear the animation queue for the element before starting a new animation.

Edit-----

the problem before is that you were adding a value to the top current value at the middle of the animation (*+=203*). I changed to animate to specific 'top' values instead of adding/substracting values to avoid bizarre jumps. Try the code now.

The first **.stop** parameter indicates whether or not to clear the queue, the second one indicates it should  jump to the end of the current animation. Feel free to change them if needed.

Comment: I find that simple `.stop()` without `true,true` works the best with `.animate()`. Just the way the animation handles itself when hovering in and out the element.

Comment: @alemangui - thanks! I tried using stop() before and it didn't produce desired result, but that was because i was using relative rather than static values! This still isn't how I did it before, and maybe i'll never remember, but this has produced a nice result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a boolean variable, lets call it `animating`, beginning with `false.`

When mouse hovers, before starting the animation, check if `animating` is false, if it is the animation starts, and you change its value to `true`.

Else, do nothing.

When the animation is done, (use the callback function) set `animating` value back to `false`.

Comment: I know this is an very old thread, but I believe this is how it should be done. Using `stop()` will stop the current animation, but probably you want it to finish first.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

```
$(this).stop().delay(300).animate({top:"+=203"}, 1000)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It stops the animation halfway then starts from the beginning but from the halfway down position, so ends up moving my element down the page!

Comment: Jon, if you are using the stop() I'm not sure why you need the 300 ms delay. Have you tried the code I put below?

Comment: Alemangui - I'm not using stop(), see my above comment for why.

Comment: Have just added stop() as suggested, look what happens!

Comment: @JonHudson loose the `+=` and `-=`. What is happening with the animate  / stop is this: When the animation stops, it immediately adds or removes from the _current value_, not the initial value. So, use static values.